# How to get array values that have been append with serializeArray in php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have normal form along with `dropzone.js`, `images` and i am trying to submit it using Ajax.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
function add()
  {

    var data = $('#add').serializeArray();
    var filenames = [];
    $('.dz-preview .dz-filename').each(function() {
       var names =  $(this).find('span').text();
        filenames.push({name: 'filename', value: names });
    });
    data.push(filenames);

    }
```

Append works fine,but i got the response something like this.[image]

I can get list of all form posted element by using `$this->input->post('unit_id')` in `controller`.
How can i access this filename array?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should tried `print_r($_FILES)` in your controller.

Comment: Why don't you post your `var_dump($this->input->post('unit_id'));`

Comment: I am not getting any data in controller @D.Dimitrov

Comment: This is how i am printing array. 
print_r($_FILES);print_r($_POST['data'], $_POST);